# std::getline() and vector.push_back() crashes on jpg

Tags: c++, byte, ascii

I have a snippet of code that is trying to read from a file and push back each line into a string vector for "later use".

```
//write to vector
std::vector<std::string> file;
std::string temp;
while(std::getline(read, temp)) //"read" is an fstream object that has already been initialized
{
    file.push_back(func(temp, shift)); //"func()" returns a string (shift is an int that's been initialized already)
}
read.close();
```

This code works fine when using it on "normal text files" (any text file that has been typed out by a person/text file not containing any "special ascii characters" e.g. NULL). However, when using this code on any other file that contains "special characters" (such as a jpg, since a jpg is written in bytes not ascii characters), the program crashes with a "`Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 5.109 s Press any key to continue.`"

I've already tried to fix this problem by adding "try" and "catch" blocks, but still end up in with the same error when reading a file with "special characters"

(**please note**: the program should be able to read from "any type of file" (file extension shouldn't matter) as long as the contents of the file are all non-special ascii characters)

```
//write to vector
std::vector<std::string> file;
std::string temp;
try //getline
{
    while(std::getline(read, temp))
    {
        try //try to push back supposed string
        {
            file.push_back(func(temp, shift));
        } catch(...) //failed to push back supposed string
        {
            read.close();

            std::cerr << "[Failed to read \"" << filepath << "\"]" << std::endl;
            std::cerr << "[atf failed]" << std::endl;
        }
    }
} catch(...) //getline failed
{
    read.close();

    std::cerr << "[Failed to read \"" << filepath << "\"]" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << "[atf failed]" << std::endl;
    return false;
}
read.close();
```

The program shouldn't be trying to detect whether or not a file is a text file (since it should be able to open and read from any file that doesn't contain "special characters"), but should be able to abort when `std::getline()` or `file.push_back()` fails (I am assuming that `std::getline()` and `file.push_back()` failing is why the program is crashing)

Comment: Probably a bad idea to treat binary files as line oriented. What will happen if you get a 200gb iso image without a newline anywhere in it? :-)

Comment: *the program should be able to read from "any type of file"* -- Did you open the file as binary?  That's the way you treat it as "any type of file".

Comment: *However, when using this code on any other file that contains "special characters" (such as a jpg, since a jpg is written in bytes not ascii characters), the program crashes* -- How do you handle a file that isn't "text", but doesn't crash?  For example, a file that is not a text file, and has an EOF character, signaling the end of the file (which isn't really the end of the file).

Comment: Sounds like you need to pin down what files you can read, and how to read them.   The way apps do this is to have a set of file extensions it treats as text, and another set of file extensions that are binary.  Have the user the ability to remove or add file extensions to either "read as text" and "read as binary".

Comment: Wrong assumption. Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in your code, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running for a little bit before it finally crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires you to show a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem. See [ask] for more information. Until you do that, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to answer your question.